# Close dialog when both dialog and custom sidebar are present

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having trouble with the `google.script.host.close()` command in that it is closing my sidebar rather than the dialog.

```
function clickWeek() {
  setWeekColor('week', '#7FFF00');
  setMonthColor('month', '#d6d6c2');
  setPressColor('press', '#d6d6c2');
  setAllDataColor('allData', '#d6d6c2');
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).weekAheadCreate();
}
```

The dialog is opened from the top of the `weekAheadCreate()` fucntion as per below:

```
var htmlOutput = HtmlService
     .createHtmlOutput('<p>Please wait a moment...</p>')
     .setWidth(250)
     .setHeight(80);
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Loading');
```

Any ideas how I can force the `google.script.host.close()` to act on the dialog rather than the sidebar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**close()**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/host#close()) method closes the current dialog/sidebar, and asuming the `clickWeek()` is in your sidebar, it will close it instead of the dialog. You need to run the `close()` method inside the dialog.

How about you fire your server-side function when the dialog is created and when the `withSuccessHandler()` detects a successful return then it closes the dialog using `close()`.

You will need to use `createHtmlOutputFromFile` when creating the dialog insted of `createHtmlOutput` and inside your html use the `<script>` tag. Here's an example:

**code.gs**

```
function createDialog(){
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
       .createHtmlOutputFromFile('dialog')
       .setWidth(250)
       .setHeight(80);
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Loading');
}

function doBusyStuff(){
  // Busy stuff
}
```

**dialog.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
    (function() {
      // Runs the busy stuff and closes the dialog using .close() on success
      google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
          .doBusyStuff();
    })();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>Please wait a moment...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this @ocordova .It almost works, but unfortunately not quite! In it's current form, the google.script.host.close() doesn't appear to wait for the doBusyStuff() function to execute before closing. Instead the dialog is closed almost immediately after opening and the doBusyStuff() function is not executed. I tested with the line .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close()) commented out to see whether there was a problem with the .doBusyStuff() function, but this is not the case. It ran fine and busy stuffs were completed! Strange?

Comment: Try calling the `.close()` without the parenthesis, like this `.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)` also with an anonymous functions seems to work `.withSuccessHandler(function(){google.script.host.close()})`. No idea why. I edited my answer

Comment: Yup, that worked. Thanks so much, that had me tearing my hair out for days! :O

Comment: @ocordova: Without parentheses, .close resolves to the function; with parentheses, it resolves to the result of the call. So, .withSuccessHandler(x.close) passes the *function* and .wthSuccessHandler(x.close()) calls .close() and passes the *result* (undefined) to .withSuccessHandler().

Comment: @HardScale Makes sense. Thanks (: