# How to show the Load Indicator while running the google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

[image]

How to show the Load Indicator while running the google app script

Answer (score 4):

If you want to stop the interaction with the sheets while the image is showing and the is executing you could try to use the [`UI`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) method [`showModalDialog()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showmodaldialoguserinterface,-title).

So something like this would do the trick for what you are trying to achieve:

```js
function showDialog() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Display a modal dialog box with custom HtmlService content.
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput('<img src=https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuqJU.gif>')
    .setWidth(250)
    .setHeight(300);
  ui.showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Script Running');


}
```

If you want to have more control over the closing of the dialog you will need to do it  from the client side. Modifying the HTML object inside the `showModalDialog()`. In case you are interested in that I would suggest to take a look into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38892675/close-dialog-when-both-dialog-and-custom-sidebar-are-present).

You can also check the Apps Script documentation about [dialogs and other UI elements](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_dialogs).

Comment: Hi Raserhin, thanks for your support, I apply the above code but it showing for the only user who is running the script.

Comment: Hi Raserhin, thanks for your support, I apply the above code but it showing for the only user who is running the script.

Here I'll tell you what I'm implementing

The script is running time to time-based on the trigger. if the script runs It should show importing range till script runs successfully. This is for all the users who view the spreadsheet also for view access users. The user should not have the option to close the loading gif.

Comment: There is no way you can remove the close option to the dialog. What you could try is to invoke the [`protect`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#protect) method to the sheet object. After finishing the script you can then use the [`remove`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection.html#remove) method in the `Protection` object.